# How to get info about .apk file using terminal (shell)?

Tags: android, terminal, command, apk

I'm looking for a command to get info about apk-file like in some file managers. I wish to know package name, version. Is it possible in Android 6.0?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [apkanalyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer)

Comment: Is there standalone? I can't use an adndroid app, because these apks on system partition I can't even discover System folder, but I can discover System partition using adb.